# How to print first four characters of first and last filenames in a directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix

There are plenty of files in a directory. I would like to print first four characters of first and last filename in that directory. Suppose the files are in a directory as

```
test101.dat
test102.dat
......
......
xyzt409.dat
yreh302.dat
```

So my output will be: test and yrch

I tried with the following but it is not giving the result.

```
$directory=/xyx
h1=$(echo ls -l < $directory | head |awk '{print substr( $0,1,4)}')
t1=$(echo ls -l < $directory | tail |awk '{print substr( $0,1,4)}')
echo $h1 " " $t1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all this complexity. Use this simple BASH script:

```
# store all the content of directory into array
cd directory && arr=(*) && cd -

# first entry in array
h1="${arr[0]:0:4}"

# last entry in array
t1="${arr[-1]:0:4}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The data:

```
$ /bin/ls -1
client.py
data.txt
server.py
shittest.py
```

And the obligatory Python solution for which it suffices to call `ls -1` only once:

```
$ /bin/ls -1 | python -c "import sys;l=sys.stdin.readlines();print l[0][:4];print l[-1][:4]"
clie
shit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$directory=/xyx
h1=$(echo ls -l < $directory | head -1 |awk '{print substr( $0,1,4)}')
t1=$(echo ls -l < $directory | tail -1 |awk '{print substr( $0,1,4)}')
echo $h1 " " $t1
```